# Services There was an error loading data for the Services tab. Please try refreshing your browser and logging in again

Tags: docker, dreamfactory

Hi after a fresh DreamFactory Docker intallation I run this command:

```
docker exec -i -t dreamfactory php artisan config:clear
```

and then my all my DreamFactory Service is unacessible:

[image]

I have made more than one fresh installation and I have the same results.
Could you help me to understand which is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug !!
Please see my screenshots below. Symply canghing uncomment DF_ALWAYS_WRAP_RESOURCES in .env file whithout running artisan config:clear there is a problem in the services tab of dreamfactory.

[image]

then if you try to load your services tab you got an error

[image]

but your array isn't wrapped

[image]

if you put a # at the beginning of the same row DF_ALWAYS_WRAP_RESOURCES

[image]

your servies tab is ok

[image]

and your array is wrapped

[image]

It's a bug that breaks Services tab when you set DF_ALWAYS_WRAP_RESOURCES=true !!